# Avoid calling COUNT twice in CASE expression (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Inside a larger query, I have to COUNT a variable, then *if it is larger than 1*, have the count as a string otherwise an empty string:

```
CASE COUNT(measurement.id) > 1 THEN to_char(COUNT(measurement.id),' 999') ELSE ''
```

I'm afraid this is slow because I use COUNT() twice. Is there a better way?

Comment: The count will only be evaluated once.

Comment: That'd be great, is that in the docs somewhere?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich . . . It is very strongly implied in the definition of volatility (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-volatility.html).  I assume that this applies to aggregation functions and that `COUNT()` is properly declared to be stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression:

```
CASE COUNT(measurement.id) > 1 THEN to_char(COUNT(measurement.id),' 999') ELSE ''
```

is not slow because `COUNT()` is called twice.  The hard work of aggregating the data is the part where the key values are brought together.  The individual aggregation functions are generally not particularly expensive (there are exceptions such as `COUNT(DISTINCT)`).  So, even if it were being called multiple times, this would not be an issue.

You could change the query to something more cryptic like:

```
coalesce(to_char(nullif(count(measurement.id), 0), '999')), '')
```

This takes a count of 0, converts it to `NULL`, which is then turned into an empty string (and I *think* it would only evaluate the argument once in Postgres, although SQL Server would evaluate it twice, in which case you use `isnull()` instead of `coalesce()`).  I much prefer your version, if you feel the need to convert nice numbers into strings.

EDIT:

`COUNT()` appears to be defined as "immutable" which is even stronger than "stable".  I'm not even sure if this is correct, but that is the case on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/946).  In any case, it probably isn't called twice, but the expensive part is the `GROUP BY` anyway.

Comment: (Sorry for the small essay, I got a little carried away...)  Aggregates don't really have a declared stability class. The entry in `pg_proc` is just a placeholder, to reserve the function signature, and to prevent invocation in a non-aggregate context (note that `prosrc` is just [`aggregate_dummy`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/aa9eac45ea868e6ddabc4eb076d18be10ce84c6a/src/backend/executor/nodeAgg.c#L2888), so `IMMUTABLE` probably fits).

Comment: The whole concept of stability classes can't (easily) be applied here, as the apparent behaviour (a function mapping a set to a scalar value) is very different from the reality (a sequence of values driving a series of state transitions). Most transition functions are technically `VOLATILE`, despite their declarations, as they perform in-place updates on an accumulator. The `COUNT()` function kind of defies classification, as it actually modifies its input...

Comment: All that aside, aggregates do behave as if they were `STABLE` (even if they're not): [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70ef4/1)

Comment: @NickBarnes . . . It is not that the *functions* act like they are STABLE.  It is that the *compiler* treats them as STABLE.  Are you sure the compiler doesn't use the metadata for this?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant to say. If the planner does look at the stability flag, it appears to be getting it wrong, as `VOLATILE` function calls are being optimised away in that [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70ef4/1). They're not treated as `IMMUTABLE` either: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5efda/1). An immutable scalar function in that context would be evaluated during planning and cached for subsequent invocations of `f()`.